# How to remove not only duplicate occurrences of a column value, but also the initial value from datatable?

Tags: sql, filter, datatable

I've seen a lot of threads that are asking similar questions such as how to remove only the duplicate rows from a `DataTable`, but keeping the first occurrence of the row. I need to remove not only the duplicates, but if it has a duplicate, remove the first occurrence as well.

I'm working with C#. Below I can outline my issue a bit further, I think the best way to tackle this is via LINQ, but I'm not too well versed in it unfortunately, my mind initially goes to using `Distinct` but that obviously (at least it appears to me) keep a distinct copy of the data within the `DataTable`, which is not desired.

Initial DataTable:

| DateAddressed | EmployeeEmail | EmployeeState | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/7/2023 | johnsmith@xyz.com | NY | X1 | Y1 | Z1 |
| 3/7/2023 | janedoe@xyz.com | GA | X2 | Y1 | Z3 |
| 3/7/2023 | janedun@xyz.com | NC | X2 | Y3 | Z1 |
| 3/7/2023 | johnsmith@xyz.com | VA | X2 | Y4 | Z6 |
| 3/7/2023 | timlastname@xyz.com | AK | X6 | Y2 | Z3 |

Desired output:

| DateAddressed | EmployeeEmail | EmployeeState | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/7/2023 | janedoe@xyz.com | GA | X2 | Y1 | Z3 |
| 3/7/2023 | janedun@xyz.com | NC | X2 | Y3 | Z1 |
| 3/7/2023 | timlastname@xyz.com | AK | X6 | Y2 | Z3 |

The goal would be to remove rows based on a single unique identifier column, in this example's case it would be the `EmployeeEmail`. The overall goal would to be to have the duplicates that were removed added to an alternate DataTable for further use, while the initial DataTable would just be the initial with the duplicates removed.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NOT IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) clause with a subquery to get the result you want.

First, get a list of employeeEmail with more than one row in the query. Then, put those duplicated employeeEmail in the NOT IN clause to filter those rows out.

Here is the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e39dcd/1):

```
select
    *
from
    data_table
where
   EmployeeEmail NOT IN(
   SELECT
       EmployeeEmail
   FROM
       data_table
   GROUP BY 
       EmployeeEmail
   HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
  )
```

| DateAddressed | EmployeeEmail | EmployeeState | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-07 | `janedoe@xyz.com` | GA | X2 | Y1 | Z3 |
| 2023-03-07 | `janedun@xyz.com` | NC | X2 | Y3 | Z1 |
| 2023-03-07 | `timlastname@xyz.com` | AK | X6 | Y2 | Z3 |

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("DateAddressed", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("EmployeeEmail", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("EmployeeState", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("X", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Y", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Z", typeof(string));


            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3 / 7 / 2023", "johnsmith@xyz.com", "NY", "X1", "Y1", "Z1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3 / 7 / 2023", "janedoe@xyz.com", "GA", "X2", "Y1", "Z3" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3 / 7 / 2023", "janedun@xyz.com", "NC", "X2", "Y3", "Z1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3 / 7 / 2023", "johnsmith@xyz.com", "VA", "X2", "Y4", "Z6" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3 / 7 / 2023", "timlastname@xyz.com", "AK", "X6", "Y2", "Z3" });

            DataTable dt1 = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("EmployeeEmail")).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).First().CopyToDataTable();
            DataTable dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("EmployeeEmail")).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).First().CopyToDataTable();
```